# Rails does not recognize sqlite3 REAL datatype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have created the following table in sqlite3:

CREATE TABLE Test (
    Id          TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Count       REAL
);

But when I try to generate a model for this table, the schema.rb gives the following error:

Could not dump table "Test" because of following StandardError: Unknown type 'REAL' for column 'Count'

Is there another datatype I can use instead of real that will work with rails?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Rails' inbuilt migrations to build your table?

Comment: I'm using "ruby script\generate scaffold Test" in this case. Still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `rake db:migrate`

Also, for a count field, simply use an integer datatype instead of a float or REAL.

Comment: Count was a bad name though, I just used that for a test.
Turns out that Rails handles FLOAT just fine, it just doesn't seem to parse REAL.